# is it possible to seal JS objects automatically?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want to seal JavaScript objects as soon as they get created:

```
'use strict';

class Test {
}

const t = Object.seal(new Test());
t.p = true; // error!
```

Is there a way to do it automatically, something like below?

```
Test.sealInstances = true // I wish sealInstances was real!
const t = new Test();
t.p = true; // error
```

I know I could do this:

```
function createTest() {
  return Object.seal(new Test())
}
```

and use `createTest` everywhere but I'd like the `new Test()` syntax more.

Comment: Actually, the factory function appears cleaner. With `seal` in the constructor, you won't be able to extend your class anymore.

Comment: @georg,in my case `Test` is exported from a module. Do you think it's a good idea to export a factory instead? My hesitation is, I'd lose a handy syntax like `const { Test } = require('testModule')`.

Comment: why, what's wrong with `const {createTest} = require(...)` ?

Comment: @georg, indeed, nothing's wrong with it :) Maybe I'll stick with it, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put `Object.seal` in the constructor:

```js
'use strict';

class Test {
  constructor() {
    Object.seal(this);
  }
}

const t1 = new Test();
const t2 = new Test();
try {
  t1.p = 'p';
} catch(e) { console.log(e.message) }
try {
  t2.z = 'z';
} catch(e) { console.log(e.message) }
```

Comment: Interestingly, it requires `'use strict'` to throw like that. Is it expected/documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal - *Attempting to delete or add properties to a sealed object, or to convert a data property to accessor or vice versa, will fail, either silently or by throwing a TypeError (most commonly, although not exclusively, when in strict mode code).* So `use strict` results in an explicit error, whereas sloppy mode results in a silent failure